# Ubuntu 13.10 - Apache2 - Custom 404 - not with .htaccess

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, ubuntu-13.10

So I've spent a fair bit of trying and reading including the 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html

and I sadly can't get it all to align.

What I'm trying to do (with Ubuntu 13.10 & Apache2) is the following:
Use virtualhosts. 
Have the default site and all virtual hosts return a custom 404 page.

This 404 / html page has an image it loads as the background, so in the Apache root directory (/var/www) I have:
404.html
[images]\404-background.jpg

I've tried so many iterations (and continue to while hoping for help) that I'm not going to list them all here.  I'd like to do this within the config files and not .htaccess files.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? I apologize for the similar questions but they seem to refer to previous versions of Ubuntu / Apache (for example the new default .conf extension)

I have edited /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/localized-error-pages.conf
with

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The 404 works on the default but not in the virtualhost. I'm likely missing an directive in the VH config file.

The issue stems from the VH referencing its own DocumentRoot. In the HTML of the 404.html page I have:

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="images/404-background.jpg" class="stretch" alt="404 - Page not found." >
</div>
```

If I try an Alias approach I can get the 404.html page to load but the image reference doesn't work (because it is looking at the VH as the base)

Example VH.conf that won't reference the image:

```
Alias "/error" "/var/www/"
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
```

I've tried approaching this from

```
/etc/apache2/conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf
```

which is probably what it will take but haven't yet sorted it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - the following worked (although I wish it took a little less effort):

Copy the 404.html file to

```
/usr/share/apache2/error
```

If it is a simple page, you nearly done. Because I used CSS and Images it required a bit more work.

In your /etc/apache2/conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf add your new file for example:

```
Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
```

Now if you are using CSS and Images you have to create Aliases in each virtual host.

For example in SomeVirtualHost.conf

```
Alias /images/ "/var/www/images/"
Alias /css/ "/var/www/css/"
```

Beware of any conflicts that may arise from duplicate folder naming.
After considering that I added a folder /404resources/ and moved the 2 dependent folders.
This required an update to the 404.html page as well

Answer (score 2):

In your VirtualHost directives for the site, you could add the `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` in each of them. But you would need the 404.html document to be put in each of the VirtualHosts document root. e.x. If I have a VirtualHost for the filepath `/var/www/test` then you would put the 404 HTML document in the root of that directory.

Comment: Thank you for your post but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh, your trying to avoid adding to the VirtualHost directives?

Comment: In effect, yes. I don't want to keep duplicating files in each VH.  That just seems "wrong" although easy and would make this go away. I much prefer to set a default 404 that all VH's respect.

Comment: Well, that would be very hard to do seeing as how your trying to first find the image for the 404 in your domain, which won't be found because it isn't in the DocumentRoot of the VH directive. I would read through this file, it's very well commented. https://github.com/dankamongmen/sprezzos-world/blob/master/packaging/apache/debian/config-dir/conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf

Comment: Thank you, but as explained I've read through, edited, and been unsuccessful using this approach.